# My website looks different (fonts are missing and objects are positioned differently) online

Tags: html, css

When I open my index.html file on my computer everything on my website is how I want it. I uploaded the same files through cPanel and hosted through goDaddy, and now some fonts are missing and the website looks different. What could be going on here?

Answer (score -1):

You can open your website on Chrome *(the uploaded one that uploaded to GoDaddy)* and open the Developer Console -> Network tab to see what is the missing stuff *(indicated with the red color)*.

I think you're using the relative link for the fonts. After uploaded to host, this link is not pointed to right place anymore.

Comment: Hello, I just opened online website in Firefox, and it looks good, could this be just an issue within safari? how can I fix it. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it maybe a bug based on a specific browser. You can open Developer Console on Safari, this console will show you what is the problem. This article can show you how to open Developer Console in Safari: https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/

Comment: Thank you, I see that in the css page some code is missing, including the Font that is missing, and some more class information. Do you know how it can just be missing? I'm sure I have uploaded the right file and it is working great in Chrome an Firefox.

Comment: You can open Developer Console first, then reload the website. After website reloaded, switch to Network tab, right click on the red one and choose menu Open in new tab to see the detail information. Btw, if you're using Adblock-like extension, you can try to turn off this extension.